# Start python execution flow from where it got stopped

Tags: python

I have below two input file examples:

```
case1:

one-device:yes
number of device:01-05
first-device:
second-device:

Case2:
one-device:no
number of device:01-05
first-device:01-02
second-device:03-03
third-device:04-05
```

Now in case 1 i have only one start and end value that is 01 and 05

Functions I have is func1 to func13 . I have provided two examples

```
def func1(self, start, end):
     for i, x in enumerate (range(start, end)):
         do something
def func10 (self, start, end):
         do something

if one-device == yes: # execute func1 one time. 
    func1(arg1, agr2)

# if one-device no i need to run 3 times 
if one-device == no:
    for x in (1, 4)
        func1(star, end) # just example start and end values will changes as per inputs in this example i just defined them start end value
func2(arg1, agr2)
func3(arg1, agr2)
func4(arg1, agr2)
func5(arg1, agr2)
func6(arg1, agr2)
func7(arg1, agr2)
func8(arg1)
func9(arg1, agr2,arg3)
func10(agr1,arg2)
func11(arg1, agr2)
func12(arg1, agr2)
func13(arg1)
```

Now program execution is stopped for some reasons in case2  input example .

It got executed one time `func1` and stopped.

Now I need to provide option to user to start execution from where it got stopped.

Users knows where it got stopped.

I will provide options like this:

```
list1 = ['func1','func2','func3',.......'func13'] # list1 example

for x, y in zip(range(1, 14), list1):
    print "{}. {}".format(x, y)
input_select = raw_input("choose options")

if input_select == '1':
    list2 = ['first_device_func1', 'second_device_func1', 'third_device_func1']
    for  x, y in zip(range(1, 4), list2):
        print "{}. {}".format(x, y)
    input_select_func1 = raw_input("Choose fun from it will start")
```

In above example user selected `func1`, and then again he selected `2`.

Now my program execution must be start from user input.

Please help, as previous I have confused all so I came with input and output expected. Hope this time it will be clear.

Comment: Your `zip(range(1, 14), list1)` can be done by [`enumerate(list1, start=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Somewhat more readable that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will modify accordingly

Comment: If you want to start from where program stopped, in general you can go with generators. using `yield` keyword you can achieve. But the flow is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since your functions have varying number of arguments, I would wrap them in [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) objects and then construct some sort of structure to access them:

```
from functools import partial

def func1(.....):
    ...

def func2(.....):
    ...

functions = [
    [partial(func1, arg1, arg2), partial(func1, arg3, arg4)],
    partial(func2, arg1),
    ...
]

def print_function_list(func_list, prepend=''):
    for i, item in enumerate(func_list, start=1):
        order_signifier = "{}{}.".format(prepend, i)
        if isinstance(item, list):
            print_function_list(item, prepend=order_signifier)
        else:
            print("{:<6} {}".format(order_signifier, item.func.__name__))

def start_at():
    print("Available functions:")
    print_function_list(functions)
    choice = raw_input("Choose: ")
    return [int(i) for i in choice.split('.')]

def run_functions(start_pos, function_list):
    for i, item in enumerate(function_list, start=1):
        if i < start_pos[0]:
            continue
        if isinstance(item, list):
            if i == start_pos[0]:
                start = start_pos[1:]
            else:
                start = [1]
            run_functions(start, item)
        else:
            print("Running {}".format(item.func.__name__))
            item()

run_functions(start_at(), functions)
```

This lacks error detection of the input and could be done a lot better as a whole, but it should be enough to get you started.